# bootstrap 3 less compile error with simpless

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using bootstrap to design a web site. i downloaded the latest version of a less compiler [simpless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) from their web site. When im trying to compile bootstrap.less i am getting this

"Syntax error in carousel.less on line 83".

Or when i try to import bootstrap.less in to my custom less file

```
@import 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less'
```

it gives me another error

"Result of expressin styles.less on e.message" [undefined] is not an object"
why am i getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpLESS v1.x uses quite ancient version of the LESS compiler which is incompatible with Bootstrap 3. Upgrade to [SimpLESS 2](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/tree/2.0) or consider [alternatives](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less).

Comment: CrunchApp is great. Grab the copy off the repo, latest build rather than the site because it's one or two versions behind. Also, CodeKit for Mac is awesome. Costs 28.00 but worth every cent.

Comment: Thanks guys @ChristinaArasmoBeymer i downloaded crunch. CodeKit is not an option for me. I am using a PC :(. and i found an awesome compiler http://alphapixels.com/prepros/